# Fill missing data using a linear model

Tags: r

I have some data that looks a little like this

```
   ID year       var1      var2
1   1    1         NA 0.5632595
2   1    2  0.7546097 0.5609945
3   1    3 -0.4241935        NA
4   1    4  0.4056908 0.5890453
5   2    1 -0.8049815 0.3504281
6   2    2  0.8049250 0.4817798
7   2    3         NA        NA
8   2    4 -0.2969572 0.4985812
9   3    1  0.2909882 0.8504004
10  3    2  1.0957994 0.7365867
11  3    3 -0.2884501 0.1454566
12  3    4  0.4999331 0.7978971

tmp <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), year = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), var1 = c(NA, 0.754609745086276, 
-0.424193528509845, 0.4056908200679, -0.804981499494056, 0.804924965958355, 
NA, -0.2969572255706, 0.29098820839828, 1.09579940195461, -0.288450063674258, 
0.499933144375212), var2 = c(0.563259549904615, 0.560994466999546, 
NA, 0.589045349741355, 0.350428087171167, 0.481779781170189, 
NA, 0.498581154504791, 0.850400378694758, 0.73658673488535, 0.145456639816985, 
0.797897139331326)), .Names = c("ID", "year", "var1", "var2"), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = "data.frame")
```

What I want to be able to do, is fit a linear model for each ID to each column, i.e.

```
tmp %>% group_by(ID) %>% lm(var1 ~ year, data = .)

tmp %>% group_by(ID) %>% lm(var2 ~ year, data = .)
```

I would then use the coefficients of these models to fill in the missing (`NA`) values within each column. So for ID 1 and Variable 1, I would have a model like this:

```
coefs_id1_var1 <- coef(lm(var1 ~ year, data = tmp[tmp$ID == 1, ]))
coefs_id1_var1[1] + coefs_id1_var1[2] * tmp[1, 2]
[1] -0.1341153
```

so the missing value for ID 1 Variable 1 would be replaced by `-0.134`. My problem is that I have a LOT of variables for which I wish to do this for. I have considered an `lapply` and `split`ing on the ID, or possibly `mutate_each` however I haven't been able to get an efficient way of doing this. Any ideas?

My current solution is

```
fillWithLinMod <- function(var, df) {
  mod <- as.formula(paste0(var, " ~ year"))
  coefs <- coef(lm(mod, data = df))
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    if (is.na(df[i, var])) {
      df[i, var] <- coefs[1] + df[i, "year"] * coefs[2]
    }
  }
  df[, var][[1]]
}
```

(Note my df is a `tibble` which is why I have the subset at the end)

Then I can use the following

```
tmp$var1 <- do.call("c", lapply(split(tmp, tmp$ID), function(x) fillWithLinMod("var1", x)))
```

Comment: @Vlo I don't think so. I have essentially done Intercept + year_Coef * Year_Number

Comment: No, for each ID, I wish to fit a linear model for, say, var1, and then use that model to predict the missing values. So for ID 1, they are missing the var1 value at year 1. So the model would be Intercept + 1 * Slope. If they were missing a data point for year 2 then it would be Intercept + 2 * Slope

Comment: It's just y = mx + c that I am using

Comment: this will give you var1 for instance: `tmp %>% split(.$ID) %>% lapply(function(x) predict(lm(formula = var1 ~ year, x), x)) %>% do.call("c", .)
`

Comment: Yer that's one approach. I could create a lookup and fill in the missing data in my original df using this data, but how to do this in one go? And for multiple columns?

Comment: Good spot - fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a worker function that you can apply throughout your subsets. You pass in a data.frame and a character vector of variable names to be filled. It assumes there is a variable called 'year' as you have done in your function.

```
    fill_missing_with_lm <- function(dat, vars) {
      for(i in seq_along(vars)) {
        mod <- as.formula(paste0(vars[i], " ~ year"))
        mod <- lm(mod, dat)
        misses <- which(is.na(dat[[ vars[i] ]]))
        for(j in misses) {
          newdat <- data.frame(year = dat$year[j])
          dat[[ vars[i] ]][j] <- predict(mod, newdat)
        }
      }
      return(dat)
    }
```

Then you can apply it with this workflow (nested data.frame's) which i really like. I have found it generally helpful for handling data where you want do to something a little nuanced to subsets of rows of your data. The basic principle is the `group_by() %>% nest`. Then you use `purrr::map()` to apply your nuanced actions to each of the nested data.frames.

```
    library(dplyr)
    library(tidyr)
    library(purrr)
    filled <- tmp %>%
      group_by(ID) %>%
      nest %>%
      mutate(filled = map(data, fill_missing_with_lm, vars = c('var1', 'var2'))) %>%
      select(ID, filled) %>%
      unnest
```

Comment: This looks pretty good - I'll test it out and let you know how I get on. Thank you